# How can i restrict a user from creating tables in their own schema?

Tags: oracle

My user only has the privilege to create session, manage scheduler. But I can create tables in the schema, can I change that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The if the user is able to create a table, then he has more privs than you claim.  Here I create a user, grant him ONLY the privs you say, then connect as that user and try to create a table:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYSTEM"
SQL> create user beetle identified by bailey;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to beetle;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant manage scheduler to beetle;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select privilege
  2  from dba_sys_privs
  3  where grantee='BEETLE';

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
MANAGE SCHEDULER
CREATE SESSION

2 rows selected.

SQL> select granted_role
  2  from dba_role_privs
  3  where grantee='BEETLE';

no rows selected

SQL> select owner ||'.'||table_name,
  2         privilege
  3  from dba_tab_privs
  4  where grantee='BEETLE';

no rows selected

SQL> -- -------- create the tables
SQL> conn beetle/bailey@pdb01
Connected.
SQL> create table my_test(dob date);
create table my_test(dob date)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> -- -------- load tables
SQL> -- -------- Do the query
SQL> -- -------- clean up
SQL> conn system/halftrack@pdb01
Connected.
SQL> drop user beetle cascade;

User dropped.
```

Comment: If my user has de role "CONNECT" , may be thats the problem? I read in oracle 10g that role gives create table privileges but my DB version is 18

Comment: Betting they have the RESOURCE role. Something also to check is to give ZERO quota on tablespaces.

Comment: Sys privileges : CREATE SESSION
EXPORT FULL DATABASE
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK
MANAGE SCHEDULER

Comment: Roles : CONNECT
EXP_FULL_DATABASE

Comment: i dont know if the connect role maybe allow creating tables

Comment: _"i dont know if the connect role maybe allow creating tables"+_   So query DBA_SYS_PRIVS where grantee='connect'.   Or use Pete Finnigan's 'find_all_privs' script to get a complete listing of all privs available to a user, regardless of direct grant or inheriting via a role.  You can find the link for it [here](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00000294.htm).  The link is just text embedded in a paragraph of text, so search for it.

Comment: Man!! Thank you so much for the script link, i realize the export db role was giving the create table privilege !!